# How to split column in pandas to get null in first column if

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am trying to split my input data column into 2 columns with the help of the split in pandas by using "*" as the separator.  When I use it I get all the entries before "*"  in column1 and others in column2.

Input data:-

```
Site ID

AIR5   
3_CCN1_3_6   
3_CCN1,2,3   
12_SDP5,6,7,8,9,10  
3_CCN2a_CCN2b_CCN3  
EMM
```

Code i my using:-

```
df['Node Touch'] = df['Site ID'].str.split('_').str.get(0).fillna(0)   
df['Site ID'] = df['Site ID'].str.split('_').str.get(1).fillna(0)
```

Output i am getting:-

```
CR ID         
2969721            AIR5          0  
2969165               3         CCN1_3_6   
2968440               3         CCN1,2,3   
2968199              12         SDP5,6,7,8,9,10    
2967663               3         CCN2a_CCN2b_CCN3   
2965269             EMM          0
```

But, I want that if "_" is not there in input data then first column should get 0 and second as column value

Expected output:-

```
 CR ID         
2969721            0       AIR5    
2969165            3       CCN1_3_6    
2968440            3       CCN1,2,3    
2968199           12       SDP5,6,7,8,9,10    
2967663            3       CCN2a_CCN2b_CCN3    
2965269            0       EMM
```

Answer (score 3):

Modify the strings that don't contain underscore and then split

```
df.loc[~df['Site ID'].str.contains('_'), 'Site ID'] = '0_' + df['Site ID']
df[['Node Touch', 'Site ID']] = df['Site ID'].str.split('_', 1, expand = True)

    Site ID             Node Touch
0   AIR5                0
1   CCN1_3_6            3
2   CCN1,2,3            3
3   SDP5,6,7,8,9,10     12
4   CCN2a_CCN2b_CCN3    3
5   EMM                 0
```

Option 2: If your Node columns is always going to be numeric, you can try this. Though I think the first solution is more straightforward

```
df[['Node Touch', 'Site ID']] = df['Site ID'].str.split('_', 1, expand = True)
df['Site ID'] = df['Site ID'].combine_first(df['Node Touch'])
df['Node Touch'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Node Touch'], errors = 'coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `extract` with regex optional capturing groups:

```
df[['Node Touch', 'Site ID']] = df['Site ID'].str.extract('(\d+)?_?(\w+)_?').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
            Site ID Node Touch
0              AIR5          0
1          CCN1_3_6          3
2              CCN1          3
3              SDP5         12
4  CCN2a_CCN2b_CCN3          3
5               EMM          0
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of extract :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to check if '_' is present in the string and to change your output accordingly. You can achieve that by using `np.where`.

```
Node_touch = df['Site ID'].str.split('_').str.get(0)  
Site_ID = df['Site ID'].str.split('_').str.get(1)
check_underscore = df['Site ID'].str.contains('_')
df['Node Touch'] = np.where(check_underscore, Node_touch, 0)   
df['Site ID'] = np.where(check_underscore, Site_ID, df['Site ID'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method using [`df.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) after split.

```
df[['Node Touch', 'Site ID']]=df['Site ID'].str.split("_",n=1,expand=True)
df.loc[df['Site ID'].isna(),['Node Touch', 'Site ID']] = df[['Node Touch', 'Site ID']].shift(axis=1).fillna(0)
print(df)

            Site ID Node Touch
0              AIR5          0
1          CCN1_3_6          3
2          CCN1,2,3          3
3   SDP5,6,7,8,9,10         12
4  CCN2a_CCN2b_CCN3          3
5               EMM          0
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks Everyone ...i used the logic of appending 1_ in prefix of non-underscore entries and it worked.

IN:-

`df.loc[~df['Site ID'].str.contains('_'), 'Site ID'] = '1_' + df['Site ID']

df[['Node Touch', 'Site ID']] = df['Site ID'].str.split('_', 1, expand = True)
print(df[['Node Touch','Site ID']])`

OUT:-

```
        Node Touch                                           Site ID   
CR ID                                                               
2969721          1                                              AIR5   
2969165          3                                          CCN1_3_6    
2968440          3                                          CCN1,2,3   
2968199         12                                   SDP5,6,7,8,9,10    
2967663          3                                  CCN2a_CCN2b_CCN3    
2965269          1                                               EMM
```

Comment: It would be good if you accept the solution that worked for you rather than posting the same as an answer